# Where can I find a list of Stack Exchange websites and descriptions?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange

Is there a single page that has a list of Stack Exchange websites, including what type of questions should go to each one and rules for acceptable questions? I have many questions that I want to direct to the correct site to ensure the quality of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you Bart for the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this - https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

But no, there's not one site over which you can just browse your way through all the abouts and faqs.  And for a given question how many sites can you possibly have it down between?  Really shouldn't be more than 2 or 3, I doubt you need to read fantasy or travel SE's FAQ to know whether to post your programming question there.

Comment: That is an awesome link. Thank you. StackExchange will not allow me to mark your answer as "the answer" until seven minutes have past. I will do it in seven minutes. Thank you.